# Dynamic checkbox toggle to stack / unstack AMCharts 4 XY columnseries / bar chart

Tags: amcharts

I have a checkbox placed separately of my XY columnseries chart. The original chart has each series.stacked = true. This works fine. I have a listener on the checkbox to toggle from the stacked columns to independent columns. It sets (toggles) the same stacked property on each series. Unfortunately nothing updates. I have tried calling invalidateData() on the chart after the property assignment - but that also doesn't work to update the stacking / unstacking function.

```
    $("#chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns").change(function () {

        chartAssetsTimeline.series.values.forEach(function (series) {

            series.stacked = !this.checked;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to the input element when you're inside the forEach method as it is scoped to the window object at that point. You'll want to save a reference to it and use that instead, or just use the event object that the `change` method provides. Also, you should use the [`each`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#each_method) function instead of iterating over the read-only `values` array.

```
$('#chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns').change(function() {
  var that = this;
  chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns.series.each(function(series) {
    series.stacked = !that.checked;
  });
});

// or
$('#chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns').change(function(e) {
  chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns.series.each(function(series) {
    series.stacked = !e.target.checked;
  });
});    

// or, preferably, with VanillaJS:
document.getElementById('chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  chartAssetsTimelineIndividualColumns.series.each(function(series) {
    series.stacked = !e.target.checked;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - it works. Also had to add a line after the series iteration to invalidateData() on the chart to get it to redraw. Without this, it changed to unstacked series, but in their stacked position.